# Venus flytrap care

Tags: venus-fly-trap

We got a small venus flytrap.  Its sitting on our windowsill where it has plenty of sunlight.  My kids read online and gave it hamburger meat.   I know this is bad, but the trap is closed and none of the other traps are open.   some of the traps have started to blacken and im not sure what to do.   Should I try to remove the meat or see if it opens on its own before I do?